# I am using UBUNTU 13.04 not able to install airtel 4G LTE dongle

Tags: 13.04

I have recently installed Ubuntu 13.04 in my PC. Everything works fine except my Airtel 4G LTE dongle (Model MF825A). Ubuntu does not give any option to select 4G LTE when setting up a mobile broadband connection.

How can Airtel 4G LTE (Model MF825A) dongle be used with Ubuntu? Are there any patches or other updates available for getting this problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

**Goto settings--> network--> and add a new connection named airtel by configuring your network with india airtel configuration **

> then try to connect the data card with that connection

Answer (score 0):

If you check the installation script, there is no ubuntu 13.04. You may have to write the script for it. Though I tried to(I hardly know much about scripting), it didn't quite work.